# Alternate for Toggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/568q9755/2/)

What Iam trying to Achieve... 
If the user clicks on 1st list item, - background is added
If the user AGAIN Clicks on same List Item - background should be removed

which is not happening. can someone plz look into this.. i tried toggleClass as well, but its not working..

Thanks!!

```
ageUrl = "";

$('.ageUrl li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ageUrl  = $(this).attr("href");

    if($(this).hasClass('selectedBg')){
        $('.ageUrl li, .ageUrl li a').removeClass('selectedBg');
    }
    else {
        //$(this).addClass('selectedBg');

        $('.ageUrl li, .ageUrl li a').removeClass('selectedBg');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('selectedBg');
        //$(this).closest('li').toggleClass('selectedBg')
        console.log(ageUrl);
    }
});

$('.crossIconSel').on('click', function(){
    alert('hi');
    $('.ageUrl li, .ageUrl li a').removeClass('selectedBg, crossIconSel');  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/568q9755/3/)   Try this one

```
 $('.ageUrl li a').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            ageUrl  = $(this).attr("href");

            if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('selectedBg')){
                $('.ageUrl li, .ageUrl li a').removeClass('selectedBg');
            }
            else {
                //$(this).addClass('selectedBg');

                $('.ageUrl li, .ageUrl li a').removeClass('selectedBg');
                $(this).closest('li').addClass('selectedBg');
                //$(this).closest('li').toggleClass('selectedBg')
                console.log(ageUrl);
            }
        });

        $('.crossIconSel').on('click', function(){
            alert('hi');
            $('.ageUrl li, .ageUrl li a').removeClass('selectedBg, crossIconSel');  
        });
```

Comment: only this part is changed if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('selectedBg'))

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition was wrong as you were checking on `a` element that it has class `SelectedBg` whereas you have applied the class on `.closest(li)`:

Just make the `if` condition like this:

```
if ($(this).closest('li').hasClass('selectedBg')) {
    $('.ageUrl li, .ageUrl li a').removeClass('selectedBg');
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/568q9755/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

Jquery

```
$('.ageUrl li a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.ageUrl li a').not(this).removeClass('selectedBg');
            if( $(this).hasClass('selectedBg')){
               $(this).removeClass('selectedBg');
            }
            else{
                $(this).addClass('selectedBg');
            }
        });
```

Working Code ->[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/568q9755/17/)